# How can I find the iOS App Store download url for my app before actually submitting it for launch?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I need to submit my (in development) app’s bundle identifier as well as a iOS download url to a 3rd party service for some integration keys.

I’ve created an app on the App Store connect. My dashboard shows a bundle id but no download url. How do I get this?

Also where does this url route as the app doesn’t exist in the App Store yet?

Comment: what you can do is put the application to Testflight, after that you can invite users to download and test your application.

Answer (score 1):

**App store URL’s will be in the following format:**

`https://apps.apple.com/[country]/app/[App–Name]/id[App-ID]?mt=8`

For example: `https://apps.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997`

It will not work on Beta testing, so you will get error message because the application is not available in App Store, but when application becomes live, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**As IchBinStudenten mentioned **
The URL will only available when you submit your app to the App store and pass the review and get submitted to the App store. 
 but you can use a services like [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) to share your app with 3rd party service provider via a share link from diawi if you don't want to use Test flight.